How to I exit the kubectl command sleep infinity and add it back to my yaml file?
my docker image gets built with the command python3 main.py so after the deployment script runs I cannot kill the process python main.py within the container. I am doing development which is heavily dependent on the environment so I have to alter the files within the container , for that reason I add an additional command to my deployment yaml file.
command :[sleep, infinity]
However when I am trying to delete that command from the deployment file by command -
kubectl edit deployment -<deployment_file>  -n (my namespace) it throws an error like this =
terminationMessagePath:/dev/termination-log terminationMessagePolicy:File]]]]]": cannot restore slice from map
My sleep infinity command is residing here:
containers:
      - command:
        - sleep
        - infinity

What shall I do in order to remove this command?

Why are you trying to do development in a replicated, remote, isolated environment?  Can you do development with the Python that's preinstalled on your host OS, and only push out to Kubernetes for final integration testing?

I am not sure why but there are multiple other things which are associated in the env. Apart from python there are other dependencies for which code relies on. So this is one of the way I am trying to do.

Edit ->
I used kubectl patch command and enter the json such that it will remove the first command in my script. The issue is now resolved.
